# Make Tooltips not overlap in amCharts Scatterplot

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I'd like to arrange tooltips to NOT overlap AND always be visible on a amcharts4 scatterplot chart.

The documentation reference

```
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/tooltips/#Making_cursor_arrange_tooltips
```

A sample implementation showing that the tooltipText is placed on the series is not providing the needed effect:

```
https://codepen.io/whoweez/pen/NWqoMvm
```

The result needed is something like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OL5KR83MoNJqAck710EW_yoxfSbkr7EM/view?usp=sharing
```